# Is the following legal: $\frac{d}{d \theta}\cos(n\theta)=\frac{d \cos n\theta}{d \cos \theta}\frac{d \cos \theta}{d \theta}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is the following application of chain rule legal? $$\dfrac{d}{d \theta}\cos(n\theta)=\dfrac{d \cos n\theta}{d \cos \theta}\dfrac{d \cos \theta}{d \theta}$$

I need to find out how $\cos n\theta$ changes in accordance to $\cos \theta$, so can I do it by dividing the left side by the second part of the right side? I'm just not used to seeing 'entering' the result like I do here when I put an $n$ inside $\cos \theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stated in a somewhat bizarre way, but basically it's true.  A better way of saying it: $\cos(n\theta) = T_n(\cos(\theta))$ (where $T_n$ happens to be a Chebyshev polynomial, assuming $n$ is a nonnegative integer), and then
$$\dfrac{d}{d\theta} \cos(n\theta) = T_n'(\cos(\theta)) \dfrac{d}{d\theta} \cos(\theta)$$